# Need to take somebody's else BHO project

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

I need to take up somebody's project who left the team.

The project relates to IE extension development.

The project I was given compiled was without .vdproj

The project is known to compile fine and register itself with internet explorer as extension.

However the files given to me, although they compile fine, are not able to register itself with internet explorer as an extension.

What needs to be done in this case?

//mouse

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using SHDocVw;
using BandObjectLib;

namespace CustomFunction
{
/// <summary>
/// Registration:
/// This is a browser helper object, which is registered as a COM When we register the 
/// SearchBar.dll using the regasm command.
/// Loading:
/// This COM object loaded for each IE window. As a window is created, it creates its own copy of the BHO; 
/// and, when that window is closed, it destroys its copy of the BHO
/// Purpose of implementing this BHO:
/// It loads the toolbar when this BHO is instantiated.
/// Code Reference: http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=509297&SiteID=1
/// </summary>
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("1D970ED5-3EDA-438d-BFFD-715931E2775B")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class InitToolbarBHO : IObjectWithSite
{
   #region Fields
   private InternetExplorer explorer;
   private const string BHOKeyName =        "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";
   #endregion

   #region Com Register/UnRegister Methods
   /// <summary>
   /// Called, when IE browser starts.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="t"></param>
   [ComRegisterFunction]
   public static void RegisterBHO(Type t)
   {
       RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKeyName, true);
       if (key == null)
       {
           key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKeyName);
       }
       string guidString = t.GUID.ToString("B");
       RegistryKey bhoKey = key.OpenSubKey(guidString, true);

       if (bhoKey == null)
       {
           bhoKey = key.CreateSubKey(guidString);
       }

       // NoExplorer:dword = 1 prevents the BHO to be loaded by Explorer
       string _name = "NoExplorer";
       object _value = (object)1;
       bhoKey.SetValue(_name, _value);
       key.Close();
       bhoKey.Close();
   }

   /// <param name="t"></param>
   [ComUnregisterFunction]
   public static void UnregisterBHO(Type t)
   {
       RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKeyName, true);
       string guidString = t.GUID.ToString("B");
       if (key != null)
       {
           key.DeleteSubKey(guidString, false);
       }
   }
  #endregion
```

Comment: What language is the BHO written in? Show us some code, because we know less than you do at this point. 
Also ;
Has the IE API changed since the BHO was written?
Can you step-through the BHO in a debug process while it's trying to attach to IE?

Comment: the bho is written in c#, The API has not changed since the BHO was written.and yes I dont know if I can step through the BHO in debug mode .. how to find that .. although the I know, the process attaches fine to internet explorer without giving any errors. as for code .. let me edit the orignal file

Comment: code updated .. please have a look

Comment: FWIW, you really should not write browser extensions in C#. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/21/agcore-addon-hangs-internet-explorer.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// NoExplorer:dword = 1 prevents the BHO to be loaded by Explorer
       string _name = "NoExplorer";
       object _value = (object)1;
       bhoKey.SetValue(_name, _value);
```

there's probably your answer, right there with the comments.
setting _value to 1 prevents the BHO to be loaded, and it happens right below there.

Comment: i thought explorer and internet explorer are two different things. will set it to 0. and report back.

Comment: setting it to 0 doesnt help either

Comment: does the extension not register at all?
or does it simply not show itself?

Comment: it doesn't register at all. i was able to find out the problem, and i was able to register it manually using regsvr32. what to do i were to make an installer that does the job of registering and unregistering it automatically

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out eventually!
Be sure to fill out the answer to this question and accept it as your answer, so your accept-rate will stay up :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect: NoExplorer prevents BHOs from being loaded in Explorer. It doesn't prevent the BHO from being registered in IE (use the `NoInternetExplorer` key for that). More info can be found at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/04/12/preventing-your-browser-helper-object-from-loading-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: I realise this, but i asked Mouse to update it for future reference.
Since i have no idea what Mouse did, i left it here.

Answer (score -2):

i was able to find out the problem, and i was able to register it manually using regsvr32.

Comment: Unless the only thing you needed to do was run regsvr32, which is I think, the normal way to register it, so maybe that's all you didn't now... . If you're going to accept your answer at least explain what you did so it might help someone else.